# How to stop form fields from shifting in a Bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

Hi this is using twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 I have a form setup that has a checkbox to the right of a dropdown. The idea is that if the user clicks the check box, it will hide the dropdown and show a new input field so the user can enter a new position title.

When the checkbox is clicked, it hides the div with the label and the div that contains the drop down.
The div with the new input label does show but the next line of the form is shifted over.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/sdcs3gka/3/

One other odd thing is that I have the second hidden div set to .hide() but it's still in view at load time but on page load, you can still see it for a brief second.

```
                            $(function () {
                            $('#NewPositionDiv').hide();
                            $('#NewlabelPosTitle').hide();
                            $('#fcbNewPos').change(function () {
                                if ($('#fcbNewPos').is(':checked')) {
                                    $('#PositionDiv').hide();
                                    $('#labelPosTitle').hide();
                                    $('#NewPositionDiv').show();
                                    $('#NewlabelPosTitle').show();
                                    $('#NewPositionName').focus();
                                } else {
                                    $('#PositionDiv').show();
                                    $('#NewPositionDiv').hide();
                                    $('#NewlabelPosTitle').hide();
                                }
                                    }).change();
                                });
```

This is the JS code that hides the div's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have added clearfix to the controls class of the replacement DIV seems to do the fix.